# Сайт узнаёт пользователя после смены IP и Header

Tags: python, post, веб-сервер, proxy, tor

Ситуация:
Есть некий сайт с онлайн-голосованием
Голоса отправляются методом POST (с одним параметром - id)
Пишу программу на python+requests, отправляю голос.
Сервер отвечает что всё хорошо, голос отправлен

Затем:
Пускаю трафик через тор/прокси, меняю header на случайный, чищу куки. Специальные сайты подтверждают что ip и header действительно изменились. Отправляю запрос... И получаю в ответ: "Вы уже голосовали за этот вариант"

Вопрос: как серверу удаётся меня узнать?

Comment: С другими подобными сайтами этот метод работает

Comment: Попробуйте включить логирование запросов и посмотреть что общего у них: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/eb1532c379e85c09a2ba33b095ce623a8383be72/requests__examples/debug_logging__requests.py#L11